# Non-jar resources in Java Web Start

Tags: java, jar

I'd like to know if it's possible to specify non-jar resources in the JNLP file. Resources such as zip files or even directories, to be automatically donwloaded in a Java WebStart application the same way jar files are.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no.  For security reasons, web start requires all resources to be in jar files(including native libraries).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WebStart/JNLP, but you can pack any file into a jar file, and then access it like this:

```
InputStream is = getClass( ).getResourceAsStream("/path/in/jar/file.png");
```